# change owner and read write permission of file

Tags: chmod, chown

I have one file with root ownership,

```
-rw-r--r--    1 root    staff  92229 Feb  6 10:51 oneFile
-rw-rw----@   1 John  staff     5242880 Feb  7 00:14 anotherFile
```

How can I change `oneFile` ownership and read write permission to be the same as `anotherFile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you mean in a bash terminal, this is the way to go:

```
sudo chmod --reference=anotherFile oneFile
sudo chown --reference=anotherFile oneFile
```

From man chmod

```
CHMOD(1)

NAME
       chmod - change file mode bits

SYNOPSIS
       chmod [OPTION]... MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
       chmod [OPTION]... OCTAL-MODE FILE...
       chmod [OPTION]... --reference=RFILE FILE...
```